# Как связывается целевой объект с функцией-обработчиком, если использовать модель событий W3C DOM уровня 2?

Tags: javascript

Привет.

1. Если я пишу `function func(){...}; document.getElementById("red").onclick=func;`, то свойство onclick станет ссылаться не на "null", а на функцию `func()`.
   Но при этом почему-то у  элемента `<div id="red"> ...</div>` в dev tools (вкладка Elements, где показаны элементы документа) **не добавляется** атрибут onclick, хотя в самом объекте div свойство onclick станет ссылаться не на "null", а на функцию `function(){...}`.

   **Вопрос:** почему не добавляется?

   Насколько я понимаю, свойства и одноименные атрибуты связаны **жестко** - если есть *стандартный* атрибут, должно быть и одноименное свойство, и наоборот.
   Странно получается: свойство есть, а атрибута одноименного - нет.
   Это я использовал базовую модель событий *DOM уровня 0*. В этом случае целевой объект связывается с функцией-обработчиком через свойство onclick.
2. Если использовать модель событий *W3C DOM уровня 2*, то запись меняется.
   Пишу `function func(){...};  document.getElementById("red").addEventListener("click", func, false);`.

   При этом свойство *onclick* объекта `document.getElementById("red")` все равно будет ссылаться на "null". То есть, в объекте *document.getElementById("red")* **нет свойства, которой ссылается на функцию-обработчик** `func()`.
   Как это вообще работает?
   Как *связывается* целевой объект с функцией-обработчиком?

Comment: хотелось бы увидеть ссылки на места в стандартах по которым сделаны выводы

Comment: какие именно выводы?

Comment: я написал так, как понимаю. если что-то неправильно - поправь

Comment: например этот: _если есть стандартный атрибут, должно быть и одноименное свойство, и наоборот._

Comment: Я, честно говоря, не нашел _DOM уровня 0_

Comment: в книгах по джаваскрипту читал, что стандартные атрибуты элемента становятся свойствами объекта ,который сделан из этого элемента. есть правила перехода от имени атрибута к имени свойства - верблюжья нотация и 3 исключения. если атрибут нестандартный, то он не становится свойством, то есть, к нему через точку (или через квадратные скобки) не добраться - используется getAttribute()

Comment: а DOM уровня 0 нет в стандартах. так назвали те правила, которых все придерживались до появления стандарта DOM 1

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42755/discussion-between-grundy-and-dimon).

Comment: Откатил ненужную метку

Comment: зачем было метку убирать? речь же про обработчики идет. две метки увеличивают шанс того, что кто-то ответит на мой вопрос)

Comment: В данном случае нет: у добавленной метки нет описания, нет подписчиков, второй вопрос с этой меткой вообще из другой области, поэтому добавление ее никак не помогает, она тут явно лишняя

Answer (score 1):

Не обязательно ваши события должны выводиться в DOM элемента, но это не влияет на то был ли установлен обработчик события.
В Ваших случаях обработчик установлен и работает просто не выводится.

Можно назначать обработчик, используя свойство DOM-элемента on<событие>.

Пример установки обработчика click:

```
<input id="elem" type="button" value="Нажми меня" />
<script>
  elem.onclick = function() {
    alert( 'Спасибо' );
  };
</script>
```

Если обработчик задан через атрибут, то браузер читает HTML-разметку, создаёт новую функцию из содержимого атрибута и записывает в свойство onclick.

**Обработчик хранится именно в DOM-свойстве, а атрибут – лишь один из способов его инициализации.**

Почитайте [Про инициализацию событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events#%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-dom-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: а событие и не вводится в DOM. DOM - это дерево ОТОБРАЖАЕМЫХ объектов-узлов. а функция-обработчик (она является и объектом, так как у функции в цепи прототипов есть Object{}), на которую, например, ссылается свойство onclick, не входит в DOM, так как у нее в цепи прототипов нет объекта Node и она не отображается на экране

Comment: Тогда Ваш вопрос совсем не понятен

Comment: почему не понятен. есть BOM, есть DOM, есть CSSOM, причем CSSOM и DOM являются частями BOM. если взять объект, например, input из Вашего примера, то он - объект-узел DOM. у него появляется "ненулевое" свойство onclick, которое сылается на безымянную функцию-обработчик (функция-это объект), эта функция обработчик, хотя и вложена в объект-узел DOM, но не принадлежит DOM (так как не отображается на экране). но при этом понятно становится - есть обработчик, и есть свойство onclick, которое на него ссылается (если использовать модель событий DOM уровня 0)

Comment: Если использовать модель событий W3C DOM уровня 2, то связи я не вижу между функцией-обработчиком и целевым объектом - свойство onclick никуда не ссылается